# Standalone of Compiz and Google Chrome with borders

Tags: 12.04, compiz, google-chrome, gnome-session, standalone-session

Hi I've found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_3xSmxTiFQ) that shows a standalone of **Google Chrome and Compiz** and I wanted to do it too!

Sadly he didn't say how to do it or anything and I even checked his site. I did the steps but when I make it and log in all I get is Google Chrome a black background and no Compiz and it's border less.

How can I perform the same thing as in the video?

Comment: He is using Chrome OS in the video and you can download it from here:http://getchrome.eu/download.php.  This is a Ubuntu site and Chrome OS is "Off Topic"  Good luck

Comment: That the video is from Chrome OS does not mean Haquimamir is running Chrome OS. This question has been [answered for Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/174883/22949) (and that answer was accepted). As this question has remained within the scope of Ask Ubuntu, let's *not* close it as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What he is doing is using compiz in standalone mode and then launching chrome.

I found some directions on how to do it and have been playing around with it for a bit.

What I did is this:

First, install the following packages

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

Then, make a file at

```
/usr/share/xsessions/compiz-session.desktop
```

And fill it with this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Compiz
Comment=This session logs you into Compiz standalone
Exec=/usr/local/bin/compiz-session
Type=Application
```

After that, you'll want to make another file at

```
/usr/local/bin/compiz-session
```

and put this in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
if test -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"; then
eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session`
fi
compiz ccp & wmpid=$!
sleep 1
if [ -f ~/.compiz-session ]; then
source ~/.compiz-session &
else
xterm &
fi
# Wait for WM
wait $wmpid
```

Set that file to the right permission:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/compiz-session
```

Note that the script above references a file ~/.compiz-session. That's going to contain a shell script with what you want to run when the session starts.

I set mine up like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-settings-daemon &
nm-applet &
bluetooth-applet &
gnome-terminal &
```

When you start compiz this way, there aren't going to be any settings enabled because you're not using Unity. In order to set that up, I used the terminal to start compiz's settings manager with the following command:

```
ccsm &
```

Then you should enable whatever settings you want. I enabled the wallpaper plugin, the window decoration plugin (to give windows their borders), the switcher plugin (so I can change windows) and various others that I wanted. Sometimes enabling or disabling a plugin will crash you to the login manager. If this happens, just log in again, your changes will be saved.

After you've set up compiz so window decoration works and you have some way of changing windows, you can change your .compiz-session file's last line from:

```
gnome-terminal &
```

to:

```
google-chrome-stable &
```

That will start Chrome when you log in.

You can press ctrl+alt+printscreen+k to log out.

I followed the directions at [webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/how-to-create-standalone-compiz-session.html) and modified it a bit to do what you wanted it to do.

Enjoy!